# How to make bar plot with mean density and SE bars

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart

I'm trying to plot the mean density of each zone (B and D) with SE bars and include letters above the bars to indicate significant differences between the zones.

Kind of like this..

[image]

I have the following data frame. I'm trying to take the mean of the "value" column for Zone B and Zone D and plot it with error bars . I'm not sure if my data formatting is the issue or not. I thought this would be a simple task, however, I'm pretty lost on how to get this to run.
Thanks in advance for the help!

```
structure(list(date = structure(c(14000, 14000, 14031, 14031, 
14061, 14061, 14092, 14092, 14123, 14123, 14184, 14184, 14214, 
14214, 14365, 14365, 14396, 14396, 14426, 14426, 14457, 14457, 
14488, 14488, 14549, 14549, 14579, 14579, 14730, 14730, 14761, 
14761, 14791, 14791, 14822, 14822, 14853, 14853, 14914, 14914, 
14944, 14944, 15095, 15095, 15126, 15126, 15156, 15156, 15187, 
15187, 15218, 15218, 15279, 15279, 15309, 15309, 15461, 15461, 
15492, 15492, 15522, 15522, 15553, 15553, 15584, 15584, 15645, 
15645, 15675, 15675, 15826, 15826, 15857, 15857, 15887, 15887, 
15918, 15918, 15949, 15949, 16010, 16010, 16040, 16040, 16191, 
16191, 16222, 16222, 16252, 16252, 16283, 16283, 16314, 16314, 
16375, 16375, 16405, 16405, 16556, 16556, 16587, 16587, 16617, 
16617, 16648, 16648, 16679, 16679, 16740, 16740, 16770, 16770, 
16953, 16953, 16983, 16983, 17014, 17014, 17045, 17045, 17106, 
17106, 17136, 17136, 17318, 17318, 17348, 17348, 17379, 17379, 
17410, 17410, 17471, 17471, 17501, 17501, 17683, 17683, 17713, 
17713, 17744, 17744, 17775, 17775, 17836, 17836, 17866, 17866
), class = "Date"), year = c(2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 
2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 
2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 
2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 
2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 
2012L, 2012L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 
2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2014L, 2014L, 
2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L), month = structure(c(5L, 
5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 
4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 
7L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 
6L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 
2L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 
4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 
6L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Aug", "Dec", "July", "June", "May", 
"Nov", "Sept"), class = "factor"), Zone = c("Zone.B", "Zone.D", 
"Zone.B", "Zone.D", "Zone.B", "Zone.D", "Zone.B", "Zone.D", "Zone.B", 
"Zone.D", "Zone.B", "Zone.D", "Zone.B", "Zone.D", "Zone.B", "Zone.D", 
"Zone.B", "Zone.D", "Zone.B", "Zone.D", "Zone.B", "Zone.D", "Zone.B", 
"Zone.D", "Zone.B", "Zone.D", "Zone.B", "Zone.D", "Zone.B", "Zone.D", 
"Zone.B", "Zone.D", "Zone.B", "Zone.D", "Zone.B", "Zone.D", "Zone.B", 
"Zone.D", "Zone.B", "Zone.D", "Zone.B", "Zone.D", "Zone.B", "Zone.D", 
"Zone.B", "Zone.D", "Zone.B", "Zone.D", "Zone.B", "Zone.D", "Zone.B", 
"Zone.D", "Zone.B", "Zone.D", "Zone.B", "Zone.D", "Zone.B", "Zone.D", 
"Zone.B", "Zone.D", "Zone.B", "Zone.D", "Zone.B", "Zone.D", "Zone.B", 
"Zone.D", "Zone.B", "Zone.D", "Zone.B", "Zone.D", "Zone.B", "Zone.D", 
"Zone.B", "Zone.D", "Zone.B", "Zone.D", "Zone.B", "Zone.D", "Zone.B", 
"Zone.D", "Zone.B", "Zone.D", "Zone.B", "Zone.D", "Zone.B", "Zone.D", 
"Zone.B", "Zone.D", "Zone.B", "Zone.D", "Zone.B", "Zone.D", "Zone.B", 
"Zone.D", "Zone.B", "Zone.D", "Zone.B", "Zone.D", "Zone.B", "Zone.D", 
"Zone.B", "Zone.D", "Zone.B", "Zone.D", "Zone.B", "Zone.D", "Zone.B", 
"Zone.D", "Zone.B", "Zone.D", "Zone.B", "Zone.D", "Zone.B", "Zone.D", 
"Zone.B", "Zone.D", "Zone.B", "Zone.D", "Zone.B", "Zone.D", "Zone.B", 
"Zone.D", "Zone.B", "Zone.D", "Zone.B", "Zone.D", "Zone.B", "Zone.D", 
"Zone.B", "Zone.D", "Zone.B", "Zone.D", "Zone.B", "Zone.D", "Zone.B", 
"Zone.D", "Zone.B", "Zone.D", "Zone.B", "Zone.D", "Zone.B", "Zone.D", 
"Zone.B", "Zone.D", "Zone.B", "Zone.D", "Zone.B", "Zone.D"), 
    value = c(1.5469086, 0.9628121, 0.5436808, 1.3583104, 0.5343952, 
    1.001405, 0.8457998, 1.9633247, 1.0564309, 1.0598237, 0.8400382, 
    0.622455, 0.5000899, 0.462802, 1.685773, 0.4686881, 2.1144817, 
    1.2159128, 1.3032429, 0.9161256, 1.7283975, 1.5130496, 1.1234053, 
    1.53157, 1.1072778, 1.3294973, 1.4293872, 1.2318001, 1.2573056, 
    2.9030824, 0.8183244, 1.9133592, 1.1637721, 1.0880351, 1.2357399, 
    1.447688, 0.8154475, 1.9440145, 0.8625087, 1.7255681, 0.7454908, 
    1.8538506, 1.0643353, 1.9391681, 1.6620765, 2.2622461, 0.8392645, 
    1.4462998, 1.0730535, 2.282335, 1.1551744, 1.1851883, 0.6946148, 
    1.1089916, 1.1289277, 0.9832297, 0.7801685, 1.3918411, 0.702675, 
    1.321903, 1.3585219, 1.671637, 1.282663, 1.6898635, 1.8615806, 
    1.2897994, 1.7114777, 1.0998009, 0.7149941, 0.3424369, 1.3469518, 
    5.3418421, 3.2474936, 3.6502369, 1.2859735, 0.9634012, 2.2181734, 
    2.5195328, 2.2866214, 1.1138549, 0.630082, 0.8241262, 0.8444934, 
    0.5658561, 0.5130557, 0.7943081, 0.2296881, 1.7998841, 0.742587, 
    1.1508025, 0.6200843, 1.2819195, 0.3960585, 1.161959, 0.3980511, 
    0.7375606, 0.3009843, 0.6061867, 1.2674316, 5.4225521, 1.018414, 
    3.5031324, 1.2698522, 1.2475438, 1.0985706, 1.3307636, 1.1795278, 
    1.1892627, 0.6699403, 1.4401562, 0.91998, 1.7972394, 0.5443802, 
    2.3273397, 0.6212349, 0.9363671, 1.2685108, 1.7920707, 1.6758284, 
    1.3687859, 0.8589559, 1.1374661, 0.829899, 0.8522818, 1.2096848, 
    1.8674565, 1.7883816, 1.548762, 2.273268, 1.5071044, 2.3455175, 
    1.8381368, 1.7463599, 1.9304698, 0.8478681, 0.9660615, 4.2659266, 
    1.2897004, 1.8813193, 1.695709, 3.6125893, 1.6265312, 2.5180816, 
    0.9977127, 1.3147816, 1.3784422, 1.4117959, 1.6234253)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -148L))
```

Comment: you need to aggregate across some dimensions of the data set to get standard deviations for the `year, month, zone` and then use those to calculate errors for your data...this is a reasonable starting place to figure it out: https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/4-barplot-with-error-bar.html As is, it is not clear what you mean because your graph examples show different data than your dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option with [ggpubr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggpubr/ggpubr.pdf), it’s a good package for adding statistics to plots.

```
library (ggpubr)

ggbarplot(df, 
x = "Zone", 
y = "value", 
fill = "Zone", 
error.plot = "upper_errorbar", #adds upper bar for se
add = "mean_se" # adds summary mean and se
)+ 
stat_compare_means(
size = 8, # adjust label size
label.y.npc = 0.3, # adjust y pos of label
aes(
label = cut(..p.., 
breaks = c(-Inf, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.05, Inf),
labels = c("aaaa", "aaa", "aa", "a", "ns")))) # adds label for different cut off values of p.
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this answer your question? As you suggested I computed the mean of value by Zone as well as the standard deviation:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(Zone) %>% 
  summarise(Mean = mean(value), SE = sd(value)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Zone, Mean)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Mean - SE, ymax = Mean + SE), width = .1) +
  geom_text(aes(label = gsub("Zone.", "", Zone), y = Mean + SE + .1))
```

[image]